# How to make iris update the selector automatically when clicking on an input having a value?

Tags: jquery

There is a field which I want to associate with [Iris](https://github.com/Automattic/Iris) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jquery-ui.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/iris.js}"></script>

<div class="mb-5">
    <label for="" class="form-label form-labe-custom me-2">Couleur :</label>
    <div class="mb-3 parent-select2-colors">
         <input type="text" class="couleurpicker form-control" name="couleur" maxlength="7" />
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".couleurpicker").iris({
        width: 300,
        hide: true,
        mode:'hsl',
        controls: {
            horiz:'s',
            vert:'l',
            strip:'h'
        },
        border:true,
        change:function(event, ui) {
            $(event.target).attr('style','background-color: '+ui.color.toString()+' !important');
        }
    });
    $(document).on("click", function (e) {
        if ( ! $(e.target).is(".iris-picker-inner") ) {
            $('.couleurpicker').iris('hide');
        }
    });
    $('.couleurpicker').on("click", function (event) {
        $('.couleurpicker').iris('hide');
        $(this).iris('show');
        return false;
    });
    
    ...
    
    // when entering the form in update mode :
    $("#formEdit input[name='couleur']").val(rowData.couleur);
    ...
});
```

When in update mode the field has a value set. What I want is iris to place the round selector of color and the vertical bar to select the color associated to the field :

[image]

How to achieve that ?

Comment: Could you add a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pre-select *color* in iris you can use "color" option and pass the color which you need to set.

***Demo Code***:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".couleurpicker").iris({
    width: 300,
    hide: true,
    mode: 'hsl',
    controls: {
      horiz: 's',
      vert: 'l',
      strip: 'h'
    },
    border: true,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      $(event.target).attr('style', 'background-color: ' + ui.color.toString() + ' !important');
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is(".iris-picker-inner")) {
      $('.couleurpicker').iris('hide');
    }
  });
  $('.couleurpicker').on("click", function(event) {
    $('.couleurpicker').iris('hide');
    $(this).iris('show');
    return false;
  });
  //..     
  $("input[name='couleur']").iris('color', '#9bbd4c'); //use this
                                            //^rowData.couleur
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dev.joshmoto.wtf/iris/dist/iris.min.js"></script>

<div class="mb-5">
  <label for="" class="form-label form-labe-custom me-2">Couleur :</label>
  <div class="mb-3 parent-select2-colors">
    <input type="text" class="couleurpicker form-control" name="couleur" maxlength="7" />
  </div>
</div>
```